# How to loop a video through the youtube app

Tags: android, youtube

I'd like my application to launch a specific video from the youtube app and automatically restart (loop) the video after it's finished.

I tried the following:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/v/" + youtubeID + "&loop=1&autoplay=1"));
    startActivity(intent);
```

It works well in the browser, but will not automatically restart in the youtube app.
Is it possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youtube app won't give you this option, it is possible tho with a well crafted hack, 
but will take you ages to develop.

I don't know why you want it but i don't think it's worth the time.