# Intent to play playlist in youtube app

Tags: android, youtube, playlist

I asked a question last week about [how to loop a YouTube video from the Android YouTube app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9134823/895726).  The response was that it is not feasible.

I thought of a workaround where I could start a YouTube playlist that contains a number of entries of the video that I want to loop.  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489306/intent-to-play-youtube-playlist) similar question, but it only works when playing in the browser.  I need to play the playlist from the YouTube app.  Does anyone know if it is possible to use an intent to launch the YouTube app to play a playlist?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research, I figured out how to open a playlist within the youtube app

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=" + playlist_id);
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(uri);
    i.setClassName("com.google.android.youtube", "com.google.android.youtube.app.froyo.phone.PlaylistActivity");
    startActivity(i);
```

I'm still not quite sure how to automatically start playing the first video though...

Answer (score 0):

To launch the YouTube app:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxLG2wtE7TM")));
```

The URL you would you to launch your playlist is:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=first-video-id&list=playlist-id&feature=plpp_play_all
```

I have not tested this. Try it out in your app and see if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks.  I gave it a try, but unfortunately, it didn't work.  It played the first video in the playlist but did not start playing the second.

Answer (score 0):

this app would do it for you!.. but it would be great to have a default!.

http://www.wowtechy.com/youtube-playlists-continuous-repeat-background-playback-video-cache-android/

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to launch a playlist through an intent using this URI with an ACTION_VIEW intent :

```
http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=playlist&playnext=1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Intent intent = createPlayPlaylistIntent(currentContext, playlistId);
startActivity(intent);
```